# Cucumber-How to use same registered user account everytime to run scenarios

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

```
Scenario outline:validate tooltip disappears when fund is downloaded
Given new user is registered
When User needs to navigate to some page 
And user downloads a document for <doc>
Then the tooltip disappears
Examples:
I doc  l
|Link 1|
|Link 2|
|Link 3 |
```

Everytime it takes 3 new users and executed but I need to be use only one register user .

Comment: U need to clarify the question. WHat user should be used across scenarios? Or do u want just one instead of 3 users?

Comment: Hi,I want to download the links with only one registered user but for every link it is taking 3 different users

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is create a scenario where the user can be created and stored in private static variable. This user is then used to run the actual test scenarios:

```
Example:

Scenario Create user needed for running tests
  Given I am ready to start my test
  When New user is registered
  Then New User registration is successful

Scenario outline:validate tooltip disappears when fund is downloaded
  Given The user exists
  When User needs to navigate to some page 
  And user downloads a document for <doc>
  Then the tooltip disappears
  Examples:
  I doc  l
  |Link 1|
  |Link 2|
  |Link 3 |
```

So, you can use the created user for all the scenarios.
Hope this helps

Comment: Does this answer your question?